# Microsoft Azure Custom Vision API nodeJS - classifyImageUrl() error "BadRequestImageUrl"

Tags: node.js, azure, base64, azure-cognitive-services

I try atm to classify an image via the [API from Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/custom-vision-service/node-tutorial) on nodeJS.

The network is alreaday trained and I can "connect" to the my algorithm. I want to send a base64 string as a dataUri but then I get this error-message: "Code: BadRequestImageUrl, message: Invalid image url"

The variable "img" is a base64 string (from a FHIR-Observation-Object) and correct (on a webside the url works with the base64).

I try out to senda [image](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/86/Killdeer_%28Charadrius_vociferus%29_copulating_-_portrait_crop.jpg) from Wikipedia. But then I have an other error: "NoFoundIteration / Invalid iteration"

```
const PredictionAPIClient = require("azure-cognitiveservices-customvision-prediction");
const predictionKey = "xxxx";
const endPoint = "https://southcentralus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com"
const projectId = "xxxxx";
const publishedName = "myMLName";
...
var img = 'iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAgAAAAJmCAYAAA...'; //base64
...
tempUrl= { url: 'data:image/png;base64,' + img };
...
predictor.classifyImageUrl(projectId, publishedName, tempUrl)
  .then((resultJSON) => {
       console.log("RESULT ######################")
       //console.log(resultJSON);})
  .catch((error) => {
       console.log("ERROR #####################");
       console.log(error);}
);
```

I should get a JSON form Microsoft Azure with the results.

Comment: The Data URL is not supported.
As for the NoIteration, that means `myMLName` does not match an iteration that is part of the project.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look to the documentation of the API behind the package you are using: https://southcentralus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/Custom_Vision_Prediction_3.0/operations/5c82db60bf6a2b11a8247c14

You can see that `Classify` has 2 methods:

- ClassifyImage, which is using an image in application/octet-stream
- ClassifyImageUrl, which is using an url for input

Data URL are not supported, you must use classic URL (and the image must be publicly accessible: don't use an URL pointing to an endpoint that need an authentication)

For your `iteration` error, make sure that you use your iteration name in `publishedName`, not your project name.

Example here, with value in field "Published as": 
[image: Iteration name]

Comment: Thanks for the answer and sorry for the late response. Where do I find the itteration name on http://customvision.ai/ ? thx and best regards

Comment: I edited my answer showing where you have the value displayed. You can also use the Training API 3.0 with `GetIterations` method, for example for South Central US: https://southcentralus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/Custom_Vision_Training_3.0/operations/5c771cdcbf6a2b18a0c3b815